# How to parse json file to java using boon and rest?

Tags: java, json, rest, boon

I'm trying to parse a JSON file which I get via API to pojo. After searching on internet I see boon is working with rest but I can't figure out how.
According to this [article](http://rick-hightower.blogspot.com/2014/01/boon-json-in-five-minutes-faster-json.html) it should work but....

In my code `HTTP.getJSON()` method require a map as parameter which I can't figure out what exactly this map is.

**Any genius one can give a working example of boon?**

```
public class ViewTimeline{

    public void view() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonFactory.create();
        List<String> read = IO.readLines("https://corona-api.com/timeline");

        Map<String, ?> headers = null ;
        List<Timeline> timelineList = mapper.readValue(HTTP.getJSON("https://corona-api.com/timeline", headers), List.class, Timeline.class);

    }
}
```

**TimeLine.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "updated_at",
    "date",
    "deaths",
    "confirmed",
    "recovered",
    "active",
    "new_confirmed",
    "new_recovered",
    "new_deaths",
    "is_in_progress"
})
public class Timeline {

    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;
    @JsonProperty("date")
    private String date;
    @JsonProperty("deaths")
    private Integer deaths;
    @JsonProperty("confirmed")
    private Integer confirmed;
    @JsonProperty("recovered")
    private Integer recovered;
    @JsonProperty("active")
    private Integer active;
    @JsonProperty("new_confirmed")
    private Integer newConfirmed;
    @JsonProperty("new_recovered")
    private Integer newRecovered;
    @JsonProperty("new_deaths")
    private Integer newDeaths;
    @JsonProperty("is_in_progress")
    private Boolean isInProgress;

    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    @JsonProperty("date")
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @JsonProperty("date")
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @JsonProperty("deaths")
    public Integer getDeaths() {
        return deaths;
    }

    @JsonProperty("deaths")
    public void setDeaths(Integer deaths) {
        this.deaths = deaths;
    }

    @JsonProperty("confirmed")
    public Integer getConfirmed() {
        return confirmed;
    }

    @JsonProperty("confirmed")
    public void setConfirmed(Integer confirmed) {
        this.confirmed = confirmed;
    }

    @JsonProperty("recovered")
    public Integer getRecovered() {
        return recovered;
    }

    @JsonProperty("recovered")
    public void setRecovered(Integer recovered) {
        this.recovered = recovered;
    }

    @JsonProperty("active")
    public Integer getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    @JsonProperty("active")
    public void setActive(Integer active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @JsonProperty("new_confirmed")
    public Integer getNewConfirmed() {
        return newConfirmed;
    }

    @JsonProperty("new_confirmed")
    public void setNewConfirmed(Integer newConfirmed) {
        this.newConfirmed = newConfirmed;
    }

    @JsonProperty("new_recovered")
    public Integer getNewRecovered() {
        return newRecovered;
    }

    @JsonProperty("new_recovered")
    public void setNewRecovered(Integer newRecovered) {
        this.newRecovered = newRecovered;
    }

    @JsonProperty("new_deaths")
    public Integer getNewDeaths() {
        return newDeaths;
    }

    @JsonProperty("new_deaths")
    public void setNewDeaths(Integer newDeaths) {
        this.newDeaths = newDeaths;
    }

    @JsonProperty("is_in_progress")
    public Boolean getIsInProgress() {
        return isInProgress;
    }

    @JsonProperty("is_in_progress")
    public void setIsInProgress(Boolean isInProgress) {
        this.isInProgress = isInProgress;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you already use Jackson(json processor for Java)  `import com.fasterxml.jackson...`. You can do this: `Timeline  timeLine = (new ObjectMapper()).readValue(jsonString, Timeline.class);`

Answer (score 1):

To parse an json to an object, I used Jackson. I also saw you used `Jackson` at mapping in `Timeline`.

Jackson Core: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.11.0

Jackson Databind: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.0

Jackson Annotation: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.11.0

This is the way I handled it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    //my method to read content from website.
    //using apache http
    String jsonApi = getApi();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //todo JsonProcessingException
    JsonNode data = objectMapper.readTree(jsonApi);

    //get data field from data, which is an array
    //todo This can throws error if data field is missing
    JsonNode dataArray = data.get("data");

    List<Timeline> timelineList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(dataArray.isArray()){

        for(JsonNode line : dataArray){

            //todo this can throws errors. need to handle it.
            Timeline timeline = objectMapper.readValue(line.toString(), Timeline.class);

            timelineList.add(timeline);

        }

    }else{
        System.out.println("JsonApi is not array: '" + jsonApi + "'");
    }

    System.out.println("Size: " + timelineList.size());
    for(Timeline timeline : timelineList){

        System.out.println(timeline.getConfirmed());

    }

}
```

At this code you should handle the exceptions. I marked them by comments.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. It is a good alternative solution, I prefer to solve the issue and use boon because it is shorter and clean code.

 `Map<String, ?> headers = ??? ;
        List<Timeline> timelineList = mapper.readValue(HTTP.getJSON("https://corona-api.com/timeline", headers), List.class, Timeline.class);
`